# redirect works but not rewriterule (mod_rewrite loaded)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Redirect works

```
Alias /www /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RedirectMatch /www/php/(.*) http://www.google.com/usingredirection/$1
</IfModule>


=> http://myserver/www/php/foo redirect to http://www.google.com/usingredirection/foo
```

So : Mod_rewrite is loaded (because of IfModule) and mod_alias too

But RewriteRule doesn't work

```
<Directory /var/www>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        Rewritebase /var/www
        RewriteRule ^/www/php/(.*)$ http://www.google.com/rule1/$1 [R,L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/rule2/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

apache log says /var/www/php/foo doesn't exist (which is true)
but why doesn't it apply rewriterule ?

All of this is in a *.conf file.
I tried to move rewrite rule in an htacess but as soon as I add a rewriteengine on it always complain 
Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden even if FollowSymLinks was on

So right now I only try to mimic the redirect using rewriterule

My ultimate goal

/www/php/*.php     serve php (and existing file) as usual

/www/php/preview/* => /www/php/preview.php?path=$1

/www/php/*         => /www/php/index.php?path=$1

Edit : After the first comments, I feel like posting the whole stuff could help

So here is the httpd.conf.
This file is not by me. It's the standard conf of a readyNAS Duo.
I just added an include at the very end to my own conf.

httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot /frontview/ui/resource/html

...

Listen 80

# Please keep this LoadModule: line here, it is needed for installation.
LoadModule perl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so
LoadModule auth_pam_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_pam.so
LoadModule auth_sys_group_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_sys_group.so
LoadModule apreq_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_apreq2.so
APREQ2_ReadLimit 2147483648
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir /etc/php5/apache2

ExtendedStatus On

User admin
Group admin

ServerAdmin admin@localhost

Options All Indexes
DocumentRoot /frontview/ui/resource/html

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\.(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|html|htm|png|css)">
    Header set Pragma: public
</Files>

UseCanonicalName Off
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile share/magic
</IfModule>

HostnameLookups Off

...

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    IndexOptions Charset=
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing NameWidth=*
    AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/images/Icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip
    ...more icons...
    AddIcon /images/Pix.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
    DefaultIcon /images/Icons/unknown.gif
    ReadmeName /html/AUTOINDEX.html
    HeaderName HEADER.html
    IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddEncoding x-compress Z
    ...more mime...
    AddType video/x-ms-wvx .wvx

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .sh .pl
</IfModule>

#AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
    ...more browser...
    # Drop the Range header when more than 5 ranges.
    # CVE-2011-3192
    SetEnvIf Range (,.*?){5,} bad-range=1
    RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range
</IfModule>

DAVLockDB /ramfs/WebDAVLock.db
DAVMinTimeout 600

Listen 443
SSLEngine On
SSL stuff ...

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment following when more graceful error message docs are used.
# Currently IE defaults it it's browser message, overriding any error
# docs we create anyway.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
# ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
# ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
# ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
# Alias /error /frontview/ui/error

<Location />
  Options ExecCGI
  DirectoryIndex redirect.html index.html index.htm index.php
</Location>

...

<Location /index.html>
  SetHandler server-status
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Location> 

Alias /images/     /frontview/ui/resource/images/
...

PerlSwitches -I /etc/frontview/addons/ui
Alias /addons/ /etc/frontview/addons/ui/

Alias /admin /frontview/ui/resource/html
<Location /admin>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    Options ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Control Panel"
    require user admin
</Location>

Alias get_handler /frontview/lib
PerlSwitches -I /frontview/lib
PerlModule Frontview
PerlModule get_handler
<Location /get_handler>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlHandler get_handler
    PerlSendHeader On
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Control Panel"
        require user admin
</Location>

Alias /np_handler /frontview/lib
<Location /np_handler>
    Options ExecCGI
        DirectoryIndex np_handler.pl 
    Allow from all
</Location>

LoadModule listhandler_module /frontview/lib/mod_listhandler.so
<Location /list_handler>
  SetHandler listhandler
</Location>

Alias /dir_list /frontview/lib/dir_list.pl
<Location /dir_list>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Control Panel"
        require user admin
    Options ExecCGI
    Allow from all
</Location>

...

the file ends with Include /etc/frontview/apache/Virtual.conf
which is
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  SSLEngine off
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/admin$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/admin
  RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/admin/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

then httpd.conf ends with an include of my file

```
Alias /www /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php


        #redirecting works
        #RedirectMatch /www/php/(.*) http://www.google.com/redirecting/$1

        RewriteEngine on
        #rewriterule dont work
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/rewriting/$1 [R,L]
</Directory>
```

I removed Rewritebase which is supposed to be unnecessary.
I removed 1 rule to make things more clear.
Right now I expected this to catch all server/www/php/* and redirects them to Google but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Since `/var/www` is your `DocumentRoot` you must not use them in your rewrite rule. Have these rule instead in Apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.+?\.php)$ http://www.google.com/rule1/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/rule2/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Am I right to say that `Rewritebase /var/www` is never correct without final `/` ?

Comment: Yes but `Rewritebase /var/www/` won't be even needed here since `/var/www` is DocumentRoot here

Comment: I'm not sure about DocumentRoot. I tried to tweak the httpd.conf of a readynas duo to host my own php files. If possible I'd like not to touch this httpd.conf so I just add an include of my file after the last include in the conf. I left only 1 rule to redirect all traffic : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/rewriting/$1 [R,L] but it still doesn't work

Comment: Enable .htaccess and place this rule in root .htaccess (For enabling htaccess you can contact your hosting provider).

Comment: .htaccess is available : I can add custom 404 and it works. I can Add rewriterule but they are ignored. I can't add "RewriteEngine on" directive the server fails with "Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden" even if there's options +FollowSymLInks a in the htaccess.

Comment: You need to have `AllowOverride All` and `Options All` in Apache config to be able to use all directives in htaccess